# Show activity feed only to Facebook users who are logged in

Tags: facebook

I want to show the activity feed on my website only to those users that are logged in to their Facebook account. I was wondering if this was possible using Javascript or PHP.

To call the activity feed on the page, I'm using

> < fb:activity site=SITE_URL app_id=APPLICATION_ID >

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the option doesn't exist on the plugin, you will have to write your own.

However, you could get tricky, and just check their login status to your app via Javascript SDK's `FB.getLoginStatus()`, then insert the activity plugin into the page and then call `FB.XFBML.parse()`.